# How to define a Alternative Label inside parenthesesn

Tags: antlr4

This is part of my parser grammar:

```
expression: 
    multiplyingExpression
   (
   PLUS multiplyingExpression  #plus
   | MINUS multiplyingExpression #minus 
   )*;
```

I want to define plus and minus Alternative Label, apparently it doesn't allow me to do so.

at #plus and @minus it gives me the error:

**missing RPAREN at '#' while look for rule element**

Anybody knows how to achieve this whithout changing the structure of this rule's definition?

Answer (score 2):

An alt label can only be defined on the outer edge (non-nested) of an alt. Therefore, cannot be done without changing the structure of the rule.

What can be done is to use an ordinary label to effectively achieve the desired result.

```
expression: 
    multiplyingExpression
    ( type+=PLUS  multiplyingExpression
    | type+=MINUS multiplyingExpression
    )*;
```

The result is that the `ExpressionContext` will contain `List<Token> type;` whose successive values will, by inference, identify the alts matched.